# Problem in opera mini in lumia 730

Tags: apps

i am using lumia 730 and recently downloaded opera mini but as soon as i open it, it asks me to accept the terms and condition but i can not find the accept option anywhere.[image] whereas when i installed the same application on my lumia 620 ( windows 8.1 developer preview) i can clearly see the accept option. [image]
I wan this app on my lumia 730, does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Tried using the magnifier? You can activate it somewhere in the settings of your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the accept button is hidden below you software Windows buttons. Can you perhaps scroll / pinch to zoom so you might see the button? Some phones can also minimize the button bar when an app is open - not sure if this works on the Lumia 730. Try checking your settings.

AFAIK opera is still in beta on Windows phone, so try contacting them for a fix.

Comment: okay sir i will try this and get back if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your screen rotation lock and accept